# Only one toggle open at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS, so please bear with me.

I am trying to create a basic content toggle, however I am struggling to get my code to only show one toggle at a time.

The code I am using is:

```
<div>
    <h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#box1"> Heading 1</a></h3> 
    <h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#box2"> Heading 2</a></h3>

</div>
<div class ="toggle" id="box1">
        box one content
</div>

<div class ="toggle" id="box2">
    box two content
</div>

$("a").click(function(){
   var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
   $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");
   $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();  
});
```

Comment: Do both contents start visible? How do you know which one you are selecting?

Answer (score 0):

It's only showing one item at a time. Click on them and you'll see:

```js
$("a").click(function(){
   var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
   $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");
   $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();  
});
```

```html
<div>
<h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#box1"> Heading 1</a></h3> 
<h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#box2"> Heading 2</a></h3>

</div>
<div class ="toggle" id="box1">
    box one content
</div>

<div class ="toggle" id="box2">
box two content
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ></script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xd146x1s/2/

If you want to hide the elements at the start just use `$(".toggle").hide();` Like this:

```js
$(".toggle").hide();

$("a").click(function(){
   var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
   $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");
   $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();  
});
```

```html
<div>
<h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#box1"> Heading 1</a></h3> 
<h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#box2"> Heading 2</a></h3>

</div>
<div class ="toggle" id="box1">
    box one content
</div>

<div class ="toggle" id="box2">
box two content
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ></script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xd146x1s/3/

Answer (score 0):

In order to have one toggle being shown at a time, you need to have a bit more control than the offered by slideToggle, since you are dealing with two opposite situations, the slideDown of the element you want to show, and the slideUp of the rest of them.

```js
//By default they all will be hidden
$('.toggle').hide();
$("a").on('click', function(){
   //fetch the element wrapped with jQuery
   var $myelement = $($(this).attr("href"));
   //Hide all elements but the selected one 
   //and shows it at the same time, since jQuery 
   //returns the object right back to allow chaining
   $('.toggle').not($myelement.slideDown('slow')).slideUp("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#box1"> Heading 1</a></h3> 
  <h3 class = "trigger"><a href="#box2"> Heading 2</a></h3>
</div>
    <div class ="toggle" id="box1">
            box one content
    </div>

    <div class ="toggle" id="box2">
        box two content
    </div>
```

Comment: @DaniP absolutely true, my mind was somewhere else at that point in time.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.